# How to Set Timeout Alert Messages using Angular 2 Alert(Toaster)

Tags: angular

I am following tutorial http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/06/25/angular-2-4-alert-toaster-notifications to make alert messages, but i have problem when set timeout the alert messages. I want after 4 or another seconds the alert was close automatic.

This is my alert.service.ts

```
private subject = new Subject<any>();
private alerts= false;

constructor(private router: Router) {
    // clear alert message on route change
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            if (this.alerts) {
                // only keep for a single location change
                this.alerts= false;
            } else {
                // clear alert
                this.subject.next();
            }
        }
    });
}

private alertMessage(message: string, alerting= false, type: string) {
    this.alerts = alerting;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    this.subject.next({ type: type, msg: message });
}

public success(message: string, alerting = false) {
    this.alertMessage(message, alerting, 'success');

    setTimeout(() => {
         this.subject.next();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: call this.alertMessage(message, alerting, 'success'); in settimout arrow function

Comment: if i call this.alertMessage in settimeout function the output is alert messages was shows after 3 seconds @TheParam